# Normal to a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am starting a book on PDE and there is the following sentence:

"The fundamental idea is that $u(x,y)$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, as remembered the direction of the normal of the surface is given by the vector $(u_x,u_y,-1)$

How did they get to this vector?

Comment: "The fundamental idea is that $u(x,y)$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, as remembered the direction of the normal of the surface is given by the vector $(u_x, u_y, −1)$" is ungrammatical.  Get a new book.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it is a translation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that a vector that is normal to the surface parametrized by $\Psi:(x,y) \mapsto (x,y,u(x,y))$ has to be orthogonal to the tangent vectors
$$ \Psi_x=(1,0,u_x) \quad \text{and} \quad \Psi_y = (0,1,u_y), $$
and hence parallel to their cross product
$$ \Psi_x \times \Psi_y = (1,0,u_x) \times (0,1,u_y) = (-u_x, -u_y, 1) = -(u_x, u_y, -1). $$